# Does Crashlytics encounter assertionFailure as crash?

Tags: ios, firebase, assert, crashlytics

I'm a bit confused and can't find proper information about this case. As we all know from docs:

> Use this function to stop the program, without impacting the
>   performance of shipping code, when control flow is not expected to
>   reach the call—for example, in the default case of a switch where you
>   have knowledge that one of the other cases must be satisfied. To
>   protect code from invalid usage in Release builds, see
>   preconditionFailure(_:file:line:).

However, I'm getting crash report in `Crashlytics` when my `asserionFailure` fires.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0c15efc specialized _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 440
1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0a316b8 assertionFailure(_:file:line:) + 96
2  OneFit                         0x100a3d238 AdditionalUserInfoRouter.enqueueRoute(with:animated:completion:) + 64 (AdditionalUserInfoRouter.swift:64)
3  OneFit                         0x100a53040 protocol witness for MVVMRouter.enqueueRoute(with:animated:completion:) in conformance AdditionalUserInfoRouter + 4374458432 (<compiler-generated>:4374458432)
4  OneFit                         0x100638224 MVVMRouter.enqueueRoute(with:) + 32 (MVVMRouter.swift:32)
5  OneFit                         0x100a6a6c8 closure #2 in AdditionalUserInfoViewModel.close() + 132 (AdditionalUserInfoViewModel.swift:132)
6  OneFit                         0x100a676a0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed [Subscription]) -> (@error @owned Error) + 4374541984 (<compiler-generated>:4374541984)
7  OneFit                         0x100a6fb94 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed [Subscription]) -> (@error @owned Error) + 4374576020 (<compiler-generated>:4374576020)
8  PromiseKit                     0x10344d048 $s10PromiseKit8ThenablePAAE4done2on5flags_AA0A0CyytGSo17OS_dispatch_queueCSg_8Dispatch0J13WorkItemFlagsVSgy1TQzKctFyAA6ResultOyARGcfU_yycfU_ + 64
9  PromiseKit                     0x103426614 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 28
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a35a9610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a35aa184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a355c1d0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1044
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1a385a3c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1a38553b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1a38548bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
16 GraphicsServices               0x1ad6c0328 GSEventRunModal + 104
17 UIKitCore                      0x1a78ea6d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
18 OneFit                         0x1003b3784 main + 39 (AppDelegate.swift:39)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a36df460 start + 4
```

---

Does `Crashlytics` logs asserts as crashes or I have some real crash?

**UPD:** Firebase/Crashlytics support response:

> I don't know of any particular Crashlytics-related behavior around
>   assertionFailure, and unless it's terminating the main app thread I
>   would not expect us to view it as a crash. I see there's already an
>   answer on the stackoverflow post - does that clear things up?

Comment: As far as I can see symbols of, I assume your, OneFit module, this is Debug build, so what's wrong? All `assert*` are disabled in Release build, but intentionally present in Debug to show you unexpected case. You've got into unexpected line, assert fired, and if it is not under Xcode it is crash (actually in Xcode it is also crash, but intercepted).

Comment: @Asperi Hello, thanks for your response, but it is `release` build. I have separated targets for `dev` and `prod`. I almost never build release target for development, but still I have 10-15 crash of this kind every week.

Comment: In Release build there should not be your app symbols, so it is only _nominal_ release build. Anyway you should review code where assert happens and fix it, even though asserts are legal dev instrument I would recommend to avoid it is usage at all and handle corresponding situations explicitly (plus create log).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assertions are not supposed to be enabled in `release` builds with `-O` optimisations level. This means that in final `release` code there will be like a blank line and so Crashlytics has nothing to crash at.

Double-check your target's `build settings`, if you created it from scratch or copied it from debug you may have left assertions enabled.

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1539616-assertionfailure#discussion):

> In playgrounds and -Onone builds (the default for Xcode’s Debug
>   configuration), stop program execution in a debuggable state after
>   printing message.
>
> In -O builds, has no effect.
>
> In -Ounchecked builds, the optimizer may assume that this function is
>   never called. Failure to satisfy that assumption is a serious
>   programming error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see that my `Release` option for optimization level equals to `-Onone`. Does this means my code crashes on builds from App Store or what?

Comment: I was sure that we shouldn't use any kind of optimization for release...

Comment: Yes, with -Onone your code will crash if it fails an assertion check, you must use it for Debug builds.
No, the Release to public version must be fully optimized with -O.
You can, for testing purposes, distribute via TestFlight a beta version with -Onone, but not for public release.

Comment: Optimized code also runs faster and so the user experience is better.

Comment: Thanks! Let me test this, then I will submit answer